Make an Ik solver plugin for ROS1
If I want to create an IK solver plugin and make it available for all the other ROS1 packages like the kdl_kinematics_plugin or Ima_kinematics_plugin, how do I need to set the Cmake file, the plugin_description.xml and the package.xml file?
In other words I want to make a new IK solver and have it working alongside the other ROS1 packages of MoveIt for motion planning and path planning and so on like the kdl_kinematics_plugin or Ima_kinematics_plugin. What do I need to considered in the Cmake file and plugin_description.xml or package.xml file?
Here:https://github.com/Tommaso2025/Plugin/tree/master/catkin_ws_10
For trial I used the kdl_kinematics_plugin header and source files, I have only modified the CMake, the package.xml and plugin_description.xml files to have it as a custom made plugin.
PLEASE I would like some feedback on the construction of the plugin.
